# Find 'p' Tags After h Tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find Extract both the Header and Paragraph Text from a Webpage. The issue is that there are flexible number of Headers and Paragraphs after the headers with the same header tag and the paragraph tag.

Sample HTML -

```html
<h6>PHYSICAL DESCRIPTION</h6>

<p>
    <strong class="offender">YOB:</strong> 1987<br />
    <strong class="offender">RACE:</strong> WHITE<br />
    <strong class="offender">GENDER:</strong> FEMALE<br />
    <strong class="offender">HEIGHT:</strong> 5'05''<br />
    <strong class="offender">WEIGHT:</strong> 118<br />
    <strong class="offender">EYE COLOR:</strong> GREEN<br />
    <strong class="offender">HAIR COLOR:</strong> BROWN<br />
</p>


<h6>SCARS, MARKS, TATTOOS</h6>
<p>     
  &nbsp;    
</p>
```

I am using code as below -

```python
sub = soup.findAll('h6')
    print sub.text

sub = soup.findAll('p')
for strong_tag in sub.find_all('strong'):
    print strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling
```

Since headers dont include the p tags in them, i am not sure how to process the HTML in order that its written.

Is there a way that we can treat the HTML like a file and find the next h6 tags and then the next p tag and keep doing it till the end?

Comment: As you are new, it has to be said explicitly: consider *accepting an answer* as way of thanks. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Tag.find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) here:

```
for header in soup.find_all('h6'):
    para = header.find_next_sibling('p')
```

The `.find_next_sibling()` call returns the *first* `p` tag that is a next sibling of the header tag.

Demo:

```
>>> for header in soup.find_all('h6'):
...     print header.text
...     para = header.find_next_sibling('p')
...     for strong_tag in para.find_all('strong'):
...         print strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling
...     print
... 
PHYSICAL DESCRIPTION
YOB:  1987
RACE:  WHITE
GENDER:  FEMALE
HEIGHT:  5'05''
WEIGHT:  118
EYE COLOR:  GREEN
HAIR COLOR:  BROWN

SCARS, MARKS, TATTOOS
```

This *could* find the wrong `<p>` tag in case you have no paragraph between the current header and the next:

```
<h6>Foo</h6>
<div>A div, not a p</div>

<h6>Bar</h6>
<p>This <i>is</i> a paragraph</p>
```

In this case, search for either a `<p>` *or* a `<h6>` tag:

```
for header in soup.find_all('h6'):
    next_sibling = header.find_next_sibling(['p', 'h6'])
    if next_sibling.name == 'h6':
        # no <p> tag between this header and the next, skip
        continue
```

The `header.find_next_sibling(['p', 'h6'])` call will either find the next paragraph, *or* the next header, whichever comes first.

Comment: Hi Martijn.. Thanks for the idea.. Just a query.. when we run the loop for find_all('h6'),  will BS4 know that this is the first h6 tag, this is the second one and then find the next appropriate p tags.

Comment: Reason is that the page has concurrent list of h6.. p.. h6.. p.. tags.

Comment: @myloginid: yes, the tags maintain their relationship with the parse tree.

Comment: Hence i wanted to treat the HTML like a file and read it line by line with a pointer for position ... (Sorry for the multiple comments.. Enter Key Posts the comment)

Comment: @myloginid: The `.find_all()` method returns elements in document order, and when you then use `.find_next_sibling()` on a resulting element, it'll search through the object tree for a next sibling *relative to the element you called it on*, in document order.

Comment: @myloginid: BeautifulSoup gives you a document *tree*; elements contained within elements, etc. It's not linear like a file.